# Linux - Files Monitoring

Tags: linux, file-io

I'm interested to know your thoughts on a more granular form of Files management.

In a nutshell, I want to monitor file & directory changes inside my Web root directories, spanning a few servers.

In this case, I'm not looking for a version-control software.
I'm way more focused on the possibility of getting alerted exactly when a file is altered.

---

To offer a simple example, many times I want to know when an FTP user modifies files (especially important config files), but not by tailing the **vsftpd** logs with a shell script.  That would probably require a cron to **cat** out the specified log.

---

Currently, I'm running a shell script that traverses the files and only compares the last modified dates to a corresponding index of dates.  (and as you can guess, if the dates don't match, then a changed must have happened, and I flag it for review)
The downside is that I'd love to know immediately after the file change occurred.

As many of you may have experienced, like myself, our Apps, Subordinates, FTP/SSH users can make costly mistakes.  (not withstanding the rules & regs of in-house data manipulation protocols)

There you have it!
I'm honestly fishing for your thoughts, ideas, or possible solutions.

In my limited knowledge of the nuts & bolts of any `Linux` distro, I would expect there would be a manner of real-time process stats.

Comment: Sounds like a job for [inotify](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inotify).

Comment: If you want to monitor directories for file changes look into `inotify` and `incrontab`